# FTP IntegrationFlows Filters not working in Spring Integration 5.0.0.RC1

Tags: spring-integration

I have upgraded an integration flow from 4.3.12 to 5.0.0.RC1 to take advantage of the inbound stream capabilities. I'm finding that both the patternFilter and regexFilter are not filtering at all. To check that it wasn't just the streaming interface, I tried with the file based interface and I'm seeing the same results.

In 4.3.12 I had my file based flow defined by:

```
return IntegrationFlows
    .from(s -> s.ftp(ftpSessionFactory())
        .preserveTimestamp(true)
        .remoteDirectoryExpression(remoteDirectory())
        .regexFilter("sn\\.[0-9]{4}\\.txt$")
        .filter(ftpPersistantFilter())
        .localFilter(fileSystemPersistantFilter())
        .localFilename(f -> (currentUtcDay.toString("YYYYMMdd")) + "." + f)
        .localDirectory(new File(this.localDirectory)),
        e -> e.id("ftpInboundAdapter").autoStartup(true))
    .channel(MessageChannels.queue("ftpInboundResultChannel"))
    .get();
```

For consistency, here is the same definition in 5.0.0.RC1:

```
return IntegrationFlows
    .from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(ftpSessionFactory())
        .preserveTimestamp(true)
        .remoteDirectoryExpression(remoteDirectory())
        .regexFilter("sn\\.[0-9]{4}\\.txt$")
        .filter(ftpPersistantFilter())
        .localFilter(fileSystemPersistantFilter())
        .localFilename(f -> (currentUtcDay.toString("YYYYMMdd")) + "." + f)
        .localDirectory(new File(this.localDirectory)),
        e -> e.id("ftpInboundAdapter").poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)))
    .channel(MessageChannels.queue("ftpInboundResultChannel"))
    .get();
```

It is not filtering at all in 5.0.0.RC1. Has the configuration for the filters changed? Is there anything additional I need to do?

Edit:
For the next person who encounters this, here is the fix.

```
return IntegrationFlows
    .from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(ftpSessionFactory())
        .preserveTimestamp(true)
        .remoteDirectoryExpression(remoteDirectory())
        .filter(ftpPersistantFilter())
        .localFilter(fileSystemPersistantFilter())
        .localFilename(f -> (currentUtcDay.toString("YYYYMMdd")) + "." + f)
        .localDirectory(new File(this.localDirectory)),
        e -> e.id("ftpInboundAdapter").poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)))
    .channel(MessageChannels.queue("ftpInboundResultChannel"))
    .get();
```

Then I changed my ftpPersistantFilter from:

```
@Bean
public FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter ftpPersistantFilter() {
    return new FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(), "ftpPersistentAcceptOnce");
}
```

to:

```
@Bean
public CompositeFileListFilter ftpPersistantFilter() {
    CompositeFileListFilter filters = new CompositeFileListFilter();
    filters.addFilter(new FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(), "ftpPersistentAcceptOnce"));
    filters.addFilter(new FtpRegexPatternFileListFilter(regexFilter));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change in Spring Integration `5.0` is like that `.filter(ftpPersistantFilter())` fully overrides the previous filter-aware options:

```
/**
 * Configure a {@link FileListFilter} to be applied to the remote files before
 * copying them.
 * @param filter the filter.
 * @return the spec.
 */
public S filter(FileListFilter<F> filter) {
    this.synchronizer.setFilter(filter);
    return _this();
}
```

So, your `.regexFilter("sn\\.[0-9]{4}\\.txt$")` is ignored.

The change is done like this to avoid confuses with unexpected internal compositions. For example `regex` and `pattern` filters are composed together with the `FtpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RC1/reference/html/whats-new.html#__s_ftp_changes:

> All the Inbound Channel Adapters (streaming and synchronization-based) now use an appropriate `AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` implementation by default to prevent remote files duplicate downloads.

In other words: any filter-based options are mutually exclusive and the last one wins. That's much easier option to support and let end-user do not worry about unexpected mutations.

To fix your requirements you have to use `CompositeFileListFilter` for your `ftpPersistantFilter` and `FtpRegexPatternFileListFilter`.

I think we have to add some [Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-4.3-to-5.0-Migration-Guide) bullet on the matter.
Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Thank you, Artem! I updated my question with the suggested change and it works perfectly.